# Почему интерпретатор подсвечивает как ошибку setter?

Tags: python, классы, pycharm, getter, setter

Почему PyCharm подсвечивает как ошибку строку `@get_phones.setter`?
Пишет: `Names of function and decorator don't match; property accessor is not created`

```
class Phone:

def __init__(self):
    self._value = None

@property
def get_phones(self):
    return self._value

@get_phones.setter
def set_phones(self, phones):
    self._value = phones
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyCharm подсвечивает эту строку как ошибку, потому что имена декоратора и метода не совпадают.

В этом случае, декоратор называется "@get_phones.setter", а соответствующий метод называется "set_phones". Чтобы устранить эту ошибку, вам нужно изменить имя метода на "get_phones" для соответствия декоратору

```
  class Phone:

    def __init__(self):
        self._value = None

    @property
    def get_phones(self):
        return self._value

    @get_phones.setter
    def get_phones(self, phones):
        self._value = phones
```

Comment: Хорошо, но вроде в документации рекомендовано называть "get_phones" и "set_phones". Будет ли имя "get_phones" соотвествовать общепринятому подходу?

Comment: @Pain не уверен на счёт общепринятого подхода, но как вариант - убрать **get_** / **_set** и оставить только ```phones```